# Equality in distribution of Cauchy random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a Cauchy $C(1)$ random variable and let $Y_a = \frac{1+aX}{a-X}$, where $a$ is a real number. I need to prove that $(s+t)X \stackrel{d}{=}sX - \frac{t}{X}$ for $s,t>0$ using the fact that $Y_a \stackrel{d}{=} X$ for any real $a$.

Comment: By $C(1)$, do you mean standard Cauchy? Are $s,t$ real constants?

Comment: Yes. $s,t$ are real constants

Comment: @MathLover That's right. I don't want to calculate distributions directly, there must be some way to determine the result using the fact that $Y_a$ and $X$ are equal in distribution

Comment: Sorry I do not see the relation with $Y_a$ yet. If $X$ is standard Cauchy, then $X$ has the same distribution as $-X$ as it is symmetric about $0$. Also it has the same distribution as the ratio of independent standard normals $Z_1/Z_2$, so it also has the same distribution as its own reciprocal $1/X$, and that should be enough.

Comment: @BGM From the fact that the the two terms in  $sX+tX$ and $sX-\frac t X$ have the same distribution, how do you you conclude that the sums have the same distribution? The terms are not independent.

Comment: It's not quite true that $Y_a \stackrel d = X$ for any real $a$ -- note that if $a = 1$, then $Y_a = 1$ almost surely. Perhaps it is true for all other $a$? I haven't checked.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I'm sorry, there should be $Y_a = \frac {1+aX}{a-X}$

Comment: I don't believe that $Y_a$ is of any use in answering this question. @MadChemist should give more information on where he found this question and why he thinks it is true.

Comment: I have to agree with @KaviRamaMurthy. More context is needed here; is this from a textbook problem or something? What reason do you have to believe that $Y_a$ should be important? As it stands, I'm somewhat convinced that $Y_a$ is not a particularly helpful object to prove the desired result. (I could be wrong, of course.)

Comment: It's not from a textbook, it's a handout I was given in class. There were two points - finding distribution of  $Y_a$ and proving the above equality in distribution. I thought it was related in some way. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the earlier version of the question where $s$ and $t$ were not necessarily positive: this is false! Put $s=1$ and $t=-1$. Then $(s+t)X=0$. But $sX-\frac t X=X+\frac 1 X \geq 2$ since $x+\frac 1 x \geq 2$ for any nonzero real number $x$. [ The inequality $x+\frac 1 x \geq 2$ is just a re-statement of $(x-1)^{2} \geq 0$].

Comment: And what if we assume $s,t>0$?

Comment: @MadChemist can you tell us about the context?

Comment: I want to prove that for $s,t>0$ $ (s+t)X \stackrel{d}{=} sX - \frac{t}{X}$ using the fact that $X \stackrel{d}{=} Y_a$ for every $a$

Comment: @MadChemist Please edit your original post and clearly state your problem.

Comment: I edited the original post. I hope now everything is clear. I'm sorry for misunderstandings.

Comment: Note that $x + \frac 1 x \geq 2$ is false whenever $x < 0$; when trying to get it to the allegedly equivalent statement, you'd need to flip the inequality. However, your counterexample does still clearly work, because in the original question the LHS would be equal to 0 almost surely and the RHS would not. That said, I wonder if the only problem is having $s = -t$ and not just permitting negative numbers....

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake.